# Truncating division in Python 3.2

Tags: python, division

1. Is integer floor division `//` faster than float division `/` in Python 3.2? If I know I'm going to be working with integers only, should I favour `//` instead of defaulting to `/`?
2. How do I get integer truncation behaviour in Python 3.2?

   `1/2 = 0`

   `-1/2 = 0`

Thanks.

Comment: About question 1. - [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/timeit.html) is really not difficult to use.

Comment: Thanks, I'm just starting out with Python, didn't know there was such a function. Seems like / is a teeny weeny bit faster than //.

Comment: For the first question, see the enlightening first answer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396564/why-is-subtraction-faster-than-addition-in-python) question for why this is unlikely to matter much. Specifically: `The speed of the native addition and subtraction opcodes is irrelevant. It's in the noise floor, completely dwarfed by the bytecode evaluation. That's talking about one or two native instructions around thousands.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from math import (floor, ceil)
def trunc_div(a, b):
    c = a / b
    return floor(c) if c > 0 else ceil(c)
```

Test it to make sure it's right. It's late and I'm doing math while sleepy.

Actually, don't do that. While seeing if I could subclass int to do truncated division (don't do that either (also, it didn't work)), it occurred to me that `int()` itself will truncate reals, resulting in this:

```
def trunc_div(a, b):
    return int(a / b)
```

Which is a rather foolish wrapper.

So, just use float division, and truncate it with `int()`:

```
>>> int(1 / 2)
0
>>> int(-1 / 2)
0
```

This gets you pretty close to the infix notation you desired.

The moral of this story is... don't let your friends code while drowsy.

Comment: Thanks, I knew something like this would work, was simply wondering if there were such a native language feature in Python so I can use an infix operator instead of a function.

Comment: This doesn't work if the number is too large for a float to represent. A reliable solution is to perform the operation on the absolute value, then set the sign afterward.

Answer (score 2):

Here's what I have for truncation division after some trial and error. This handles arbitrarily large integers.

```
def truncdiv(num : int, denom : int):
    if (num < 0) != (denom < 0):
        return -(num // -denom)
    else:
        return num // denom
```

I found this in looking for a truncated divmod (quotient-remainder). What I have is analogous:

```
def truncdivmod(num : int, denom : int):
    if (num < 0) != (denom < 0):
        q, r = divmod(num, -denom)
        return [-q, r]
    else:
        return divmod(num, denom)
```

Comment: there was a removed discussion: this has been updated for correct python syntax